# Making a simple layout with a sidebar in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a simple HTML layout with a sidebar on the left and a container at it's right. 
The CSS Codes i wrote are these:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
.sidebar,.content{
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px;
    border:1px solid #777;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
.content{
    width: 630px;
}
```

And the simple HTML Follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="sidebar"> </div>

  <div class="content">  </div>
</body>
```

But It doesn't seem to work though i thought using float:left solves the problem, but it seems that the right one is going on top of another.

JSFiddle: [Click here to see the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hchree0/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more responsive way of doing it using flexbox:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar,
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px;
    border:1px solid #777;
}

.sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.content {
    flex-grow: 5;
    min-width: 630px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>These are list items</li>
                <li>These are list items</li>
                <li>These are list items</li>
                <li>These are list items</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Content</h1>
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can change how much space the sidebar of the content divs are given by increasing/decreasing the `flex-grow`value. This way it will automatically resize of different screen sizes. You can then also hide the sidebar when the user is on a mobile device or stack them, depending on what you would prefer.

Answer (score 2):

A modern and elegant solution to this would be to use CSS Grid.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar main";
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    // sidebar content
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
    // main page content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another div wich has a `overflow: hidden;`

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}  
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar, .content{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px;
  border:1px solid #777;
}
.sidebar{
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
.content{
  width: 630px;
}
```

Example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/1hchree0/3/

Answer (score 0):

check fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/1hchree0/1/

Updated your css :

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
.sidebar, .content{
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:1px solid #777;
}
.sidebar{

    width: 300px;
    /* float:left  Removed*/
    left:0; /* Added */
    top:0; /* Added */
    position: absolute;
}
.content{
    width: 630px;
    margin-left:300px /* Added */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="sidebar"> </div>

  <div class="content">  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. But is this the only pure way of  doing it?

Comment: No, but it's preferred one.

Comment: @BlaiseM its not the only wat to do this, but its the easiest one and prefered by most of the Developers.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this with float:**

CSS:

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .sidebar, .content {
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border:1px solid #777;
        float:left;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 300px; /*change it according to the design*/
    }
    body:after {
        clear:both;
        content:"";
        display:block; /*For clearing float*/
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1hchree0/2/

**Using `display:inline-block`:**

CSS:

```
        body {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .sidebar, .content {
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border:1px solid #777;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 300px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="sidebar"></div><div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1hchree0/4/

**Using `display:table`**

CSS:

```
        body {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        display:table;
    }
    .sidebar, .content {
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border:1px solid #777;
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 500px;
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1hchree0/8/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/1hchree0/7/)

```
 .content{
            width: 630px;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 45px; /* change as per your need */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need definitely one container div otherwise this code dont work older browsers.

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>    
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
.container {
    width:1015px;
}
    .sidebar,.content{
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: 20px;
        border:1px solid #777;
    float: left;
    }
    .sidebar{
        width: 300px;

    }
    .content{
        width: 630px;

    }
```

Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/blaisemugisha/1hchree0/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```css
body{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container .footer {
  background: #4C92FF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.container .content {
  min-height: 120px;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.container .content .sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height:820px;
  float: right;
  background-color: violet;
  border-radius: 2%;

}

.container .header {
  background: #4C92FF;
  height: 80px;
  text-indent: 1%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.maincontent img{
  float: right;
  height: 150x;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
}

.maincontent table, .maincontent td, .maincontent th{
  border-style:double;
  text-align: center;
}

.hitCounter{
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.maincontent{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Trains in Sri Lanka</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h3>Social Profiles</h3>
      <table>
        <tr style="align-content: center">
          <th><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/fb.png" style="height: 50px; width: 50px"/></a></th>
          <th><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/g.png" style="height: 50px; width: 50px"/></th>
          <th><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/li.png" style="height: 50px; width: 50px"/></th>
        </tr>
      </table>    
      <hr>
      <h3>Hit Counter</h3>
      <div class="hitCounter">
        <a href='https://freehitcounters.org/' >freehitcounters.org</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.freevisitorcounters.com/auth.php?id=40ce15186d73fda91d26f71e9ae5cc0169d382b1'></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.freevisitorcounters.com/en/home/counter/425569/t/3"></script>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <h3>Subscribe</h3>
      <div class="subscribeBox">
        <form name="subscriptionForm">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" style="margin-left: 10%"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" style="margin-left: 30%"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <h3>Contact Author</h3>
      <div class="contactBox" style="text-align: center">
        Name:<br> XXX<br>
        <br>
        email:<br> XXX
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maincontent">
      <h2>Class M1 Locomotives</h2>
      <img src="img/m1.jpg">
      <p>In the 1950s Sri Lankan railway was seeking replacements for old rolling stock, routine replacement of which had been delayed by World War II. Specifications were for 25 locomotives with 750 hp (559 kW) power at the wheel, available from 12 mph (19 km/h) upwards, and up to an altitude of 6,200 ft (1,900 m). The train was expected to be used for suburban trains centered on Colombo, as well as mail trains in the north of the country, and trains in hill areas: approximately requirements were for a vehicle capable of pulling 550 long tons (560 t; 620 short tons) at 18 mph (29 km/h) on a gradient of 1 in 44 (2.27%) on track with 5-chain (330 ft; 101 m) reverse curves; preferably within a 80 long tons (81 t; 90 short tons) locomotive weight on 6 axles (A1A-A1A). Several firms tendered for the contact; American suppliers were unable to enter a competitive bid due to the devaluation of both the rupee and British pound.</p>
      <hr>
      <h2>Class M2 Locomotives</h2>
      <img src="img/m2.jpg">
      <p>From 1954, several batches of General Motors-manufactured locomotives were imported to Sri Lanka under "The Colombo Plan". Locally called a "Canadian" engine – there are actually two classes of Canadian engine in SLR – the other one is Class M4. Since these engine were imported under grants from the Canadian government, class M2 locomotives are named with Canadian province and city names. The last two locomotives were made in the United States and imported for Cement Corporation, Sri Lanka. But they were later attached to Sri Lanka Railways locomotive fleet. They were named after two local cities – Galle and Kankasanthurei – where the cement factories were located.</p>
      <h4>Sub classes</h4>
      <table>
        <tr> 
          <th>Sub Class</th>
          <th>Weight</th>
          <th>Axel Arrangement</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>No.of Locomotives</th>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
          <td>M2A</td>
          <td rowspan="4">79 Tonnes</td>
          <td>AIA - AIA</td>
          <td>1959</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>M2A</td>
          <td>AIA - AIA</td>
          <td>1959</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      
        <tr>
          <td>M2A</td>
          <td>AIA - AIA</td>
          <td>1959</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      
        <tr>
          <td>M2A</td>
          <td>AIA - AIA</td>
          <td>1959</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    © 2017 | Trains in Sri Lanka
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Bootstrap 5 with Font Awesome 6 Icons**

I've changed [StartBootstrap's](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin) template to use **Bootstrap 5** and **Vanilla JS**

https://github.com/VFDouglas/reusable-codes/tree/main/bootstrap-header-sidebar

```js
'use strict';

// Configura tooltips para navegação lateral oculta
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-sidenav [data-toggle="tooltip"]').forEach(element => {
    let tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(element, {template: '<div class="tooltip navbar-sidenav-tooltip" role="tooltip" style="pointer-events: none;"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'});
});

// Alterna a navegação lateral
document.getElementById('sidenavToggler').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.body.classList.toggle('sidenav-toggled');
    document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse').forEach(element => {
        element.classList.add('collapsed');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level, .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level').forEach(element => {
        element.classList.remove('show');
    });
})

// Força a classe habilitada a ser removida quando o link for clicado
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.body.classList.remove('sidenav-toggled');
    });
});

// Previne a rolagem do conteúdo quando o mouse está sobre a barra de navegação lateral
document.querySelectorAll('body.fixed-nav .navbar-sidenav, body.fixed-nav .sidenav-toggler, body.fixed-nav .navbar-collapse').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
        let delta = event.wheelDelta || -event.detail;
        this.scrollTop += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Aparecimento do botão de rolagem para o topo
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    let scroll_distance = this.scrollY;
    let back_to_top     = document.querySelector('.back_to_top');

    if (scroll_distance > 100) {
        back_to_top.classList.remove('hide');
    }
    else {
        back_to_top.classList.add('hide');
    }
});

document.getElementById('toggleNavPosition').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('fixed-nav');
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('fixed-top');
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('static-top');
});
document.getElementById('toggleNavColor').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('navbar-dark');
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('navbar-light');

    document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('bg-dark');
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('bg-light');

    document.body.classList.toggle('bg-dark');
    document.body.classList.toggle('bg-light');
});

// Habilitando todos os tooltips
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltip_trigger_element) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltip_trigger_element);
});
```

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body.sticky-footer {
    margin-bottom: 56px;
}

body.sticky-footer .content-wrapper {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 56px - 56px);
}

body.fixed-nav {
    padding-top: 56px;
}

.content-wrapper {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    padding-top: 1rem;
}

.scroll-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 3px;
    display: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
    line-height: 45px;
}

.scroll-to-top:focus, .scroll-to-top:hover {
    color: white;
}

.scroll-to-top:hover {
    background: #343a40;
}

.scroll-to-top i {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.smaller {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.o-hidden {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.z-0 {
    z-index: 0;
}

.z-1 {
    z-index: 1;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 75vh;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after {
    float: right;
    content: '\f107';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse.collapsed:after {
    content: '\f105';
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level,
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level > li > a,
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level > li > a:focus, #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level > li > a:hover,
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level > li > a:focus,
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level > li > a {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level > li > a {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .sidenav-toggler {
    display: none;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 45px;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link:after {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    content: '\f105';
    border: none;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link .indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 21px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown.show > .nav-link:after {
    content: '\f107';
}

#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item > .dropdown-message {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav .navbar-brand {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse {
        overflow: visible;
        max-height: none;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 56px;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item > .nav-link {
        padding: 1em;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level,
    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level {
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li,
    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a,
    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a {
        padding: 1em;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a {
        padding-left: 2.75em;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a {
        padding-left: 3.75em;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link {
        min-width: 0;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link:after {
        width: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item > .dropdown-message {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}

#mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav.fixed-top .navbar-sidenav {
        height: calc(100vh - 112px);
    }

    #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: calc(100vh - 56px);
    }

    #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler > .nav-item {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler > .nav-item > .nav-link {
        padding: 1em;
    }
}

#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-dark .sidenav-toggler {
    background-color: #212529;
}

#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-dark .sidenav-toggler a i {
    color: #adb5bd;
}

#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-light .sidenav-toggler {
    background-color: #dee2e6;
}

#mainNav.fixed-top.navbar-light .sidenav-toggler a i {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 55px;
}

body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler .nav-item,
body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top .sidenav-toggler .nav-link {
    width: 55px !important;
}

body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.fixed-top #sidenavToggler i {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: 'FlipH';
}

#mainNav.static-top .sidenav-toggler {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav.static-top .sidenav-toggler {
        display: flex;
    }
}

body.sidenav-toggled #mainNav.static-top #sidenavToggler i {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: 'FlipH';
}

.content-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: white;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .content-wrapper {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
}

#sidenavToggler i {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.navbar-sidenav-tooltip.show {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body.sidenav-toggled .content-wrapper {
        margin-left: 55px;
    }
}

body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav {
    width: 55px;
}

body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-text {
    display: none;
}

body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-item,
body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-link {
    width: 55px !important;
}

body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-item:after,
body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-link:after {
    display: none;
}

body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav .nav-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

body.sidenav-toggled .navbar-sidenav-tooltip.show {
    display: flex;
}

#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after {
    color: #868e96;
}

#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item > .nav-link {
    color: #868e96;
}

#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
    color: #adb5bd;
}

#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a,
#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a {
    color: #868e96;
}

#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a:focus, #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a:hover,
#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a:focus,
#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a:hover {
    color: #adb5bd;
}

#mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link:after {
    color: #adb5bd;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav {
        background: #343a40;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a {
        color: white !important;
        background-color: #495057;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:focus, #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:hover {
        color: white;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level,
    #mainNav.navbar-dark .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level {
        background: #343a40;
    }
}

#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse:after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item > .nav-link {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a,
#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a:focus, #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level > li > a:hover,
#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a:focus,
#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level > li > a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item.dropdown > .nav-link:after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav {
        background: #f8f9fa;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a {
        color: #000 !important;
        background-color: #e9ecef;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:focus, #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav li.active a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-second-level,
    #mainNav.navbar-light .navbar-collapse .navbar-sidenav > .nav-item .sidenav-third-level {
        background: #f8f9fa;
    }
}

.card-body-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -25px;
    right: -25px;
    font-size: 5rem;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

.card-login {
    max-width: 25rem;
}

.card-register {
    max-width: 40rem;
}

footer.sticky-footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    line-height: 55px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    footer.sticky-footer {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body.sidenav-toggled footer.sticky-footer {
        width: calc(100% - 55px);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>SB Admin - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cff50367d9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top pb-2 pt-2 px-3" id="mainNav">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
                    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
                            <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Components">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseComponents" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
                            <span class="nav-link-text">Components</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseComponents">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Navbar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Cards</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Example Pages">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExamplePages" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>
                            <span class="nav-link-text">Example Pages</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseExamplePages">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Registration Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Menu Levels">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMulti" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sitemap"></i>
                            <span class="nav-link-text">Menu Levels</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseMulti">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseMulti2">Third Level</a>
                                <ul class="sidenav-third-level collapse" id="collapseMulti2">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="Link">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-link"></i>
                            <span class="nav-link-text">Link</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle me-lg-2" id="messagesDropdown" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>
                            <span class="d-lg-none">Messages
                                <span class="badge badge-pill bg-primary text-dark">12 New</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="indicator text-primary d-none d-lg-block">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header">New Messages:</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <strong>David</strong>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">Hey there!</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">View all messages</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle me-lg-2" id="alertsDropdown" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell"></i>
                            <span class="d-lg-none">Alerts
                                <span class="badge badge-pill bg-warning text-dark">6 New</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="indicator text-warning d-none d-lg-block">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header">New Alerts:</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="text-success">
                                    <strong>
                                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-fw"></i>
                                        Status Update
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">This is an automated server response message.</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <strong><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down fa-fw"></i>Status Update</strong>
                                </span>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">This is an automated server response message.</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="text-success">
                                    <strong><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-fw"></i>Status Update</strong>
                                </span>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">This is an automated server response message.</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">View all alerts</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle me-lg-2" id="alertsDropdown" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell"></i>
                            <span class="d-lg-none">Alerts
                                <span class="badge badge-pill bg-warning text-dark">6 New</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="indicator text-warning d-none d-lg-block">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header">New Alerts:</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="text-success">
                                    <strong>
                                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-fw"></i>
                                        Status Update
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">This is an automated server response message. All systems are online.</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                    <strong><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down fa-fw"></i>Status Update</strong>
                                </span>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">This is an automated server response message. All systems are online.</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="text-success">
                                    <strong><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-fw"></i>Status Update</strong>
                                </span>
                                <span class="small float-end text-muted">11:21 AM</span>
                                <div class="dropdown-message small">This is an automated server response message. All systems are online.</div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item small" href="#">View all alerts</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 mr-lg-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
                                <span class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Navbar</li>
                </ol>
                <h1>Navbar</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>The SB Admin navbar can be either fixed or static, and it supports the navbar-light and navbar-dark Bootstrap 5 classes.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="toggleNavPosition">Toggle Fixed/Static Navbar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="toggleNavColor">Toggle Navbar Color</a>
                <!-- Blank div to give the page height to preview the fixed vs. static navbar-->
                <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Scroll to Top Button -->
            <span class="back_to_top hide" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" title="Clique para voltar ao topo da p&aacute;gina">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up fa-2x"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                        <button class="btn-close" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```